# android sms application to reveal sender's location

Tags: android, eclipse

i am an android newbi. i extend my apologies for a very primitive question.
   i intend to develop an android application for sms messaging so that when the reciever recieves a message, the sender's physical location is also automatically revealed (using the GPS of sender) may be in Lat Long format. 
  My question is, how to go by this problem? 
bundles of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think.. getting the location of the sender completely depends on the sender..i.e if the sender decides to reveal his location.. only the recipient can get his location.. so.. the application you are trying to make should be in senders phone... and in this case..

create an activity with text field and a button to send the message like this..

```
  class A extends Activity
  {
    String s;
Oncreate()
{
 editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
 sendBtn  =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);

sendBtn  .setonclickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void Onclick(){
       locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
        MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 
        MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
        new MyLocationListener()
);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

if (location != null) {

    clat=location.getLatitude();
    clon=location.getLongitude();
       }
    s=editText.getText().toString()+"lat"+clat+"long"+clong
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        new Intent(this, Object.class), 0);  
     SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, s, pi, null);  
}
});

 }
```

Comment: ...plz would u explain the "new MyLocationListener()" it isnt in the code?

Comment: you need a location listener when you want updates.. but we dont want any updates.. and just want the current location.. so no need of locationlistener

Comment: ...So in the statement locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
        MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 
        MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
        new MyLocationListener())...can i use "null" in place of new MyLocationListener()?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(**this**, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(**this**, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
{
}
```

How to resolve an error in the 1st argument i.e. "**this**"?